# How can I change the background color of a UIBarButtonItem on iOS 7+?

Tags: ios, uibarbuttonitem

I'd like to indicate that a particular `UIBarButtonItem` is toggled on or off by changing its background color. Mobile Safari uses this feature to indicate whether private browsing is on or off:

[image: Off]
[image: On]

How can I do this, since there's no `backgroundColor` property on `UIBarButtonItem`?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Create a `UIButton` and use it as the custom view for the `UIBarButtonItem`. Then, set the `backgroundColor` on the button's layer:

```
UIButton* button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[button setTitle:@"Test"];
button.layer.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor].CGColor;
button.layer.cornerRadius = 4.0;

UIBarButtonItem* buttonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:button];
self.toolbarItems = @[buttonItem];
```

Comment: You also have to set the size of the button, otherwise it doesn't appear in iOS 7+, [button setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 80, 20)];

Comment: Or you can let it set its own size: [button sizeToFit];

Comment: Does anyone know why this does not work for UINavigation UIBarButtonItems?

Answer (score 1):

You could instead just use two images. One for selected and one for unselected

```
- (void)setBackgroundImage:(UIImage *)backgroundImage forState:(UIControlState)state barMetrics:(UIBarMetrics)barMetrics
```

The above function should help you do this

Comment: It is Available in iOS 5.0 and later for UIBarButtonItem and it seems to be the only current solution (iOS 9.0)

Answer (score 0):

Swift 5 Answer

```
        let rightBarCancelButton = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 30, height: 30))
        let cancelImage = UIImage(systemName: "multiply")
        rightBarCancelButton.setImage(cancelImage, for: .normal)
        rightBarCancelButton.layer.cornerRadius = 15
        rightBarCancelButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray
        
        let rightBarButton = UIBarButtonItem(customView: rightBarCancelButton)
        navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = rightBarButton
```

Works like a charm!