# Using a UIButton into Navigation Bar using StoryBoard

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

Essentially I have a UIButton created in StoryBoards that I would like to drag into the navigation bar. This UIButton has an action associated with it when touched but all touch events stop working when I drag this UIButton into the navigation bar.

Is there additional code I need to the IBAction item when doing this?

One of the main reasons I want to add a UIButton instead of a BarButtonItem to the navigation bar is simply because it allows me to add a background color and curve the edges of the button.

Comment: Can you show a screenshot of your storyboard?

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26348952/how-can-i-change-the-background-color-of-a-uibarbuttonitem-on-ios-7) help?

Comment: @Sweeper That looks like exactly what I need I just don't know how it can be done in Swift 5. Can you please show how it can be written? I really appreciate your help

Comment: I will test it shortly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can do it in the storyboard. You have to do it in code, using the [`init(customView:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uibarbuttonitem/1617151-init) initialiser.

```
let myCustomButtonWithBackgroundsAndStuff = UIButton(type: .custom)
...

// this is the equivalent of connecting the IBAction, in code form, in case you didn't know
myCustomButtonWithBackgroundsAndStuff.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonAction), for: .touchUpInside)
let barButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: myCustomButton)
navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = barButtonItem
// or append to rightBarButtonItems if you have other bar button items

...
@objc func buttonAction() {
    ...
}
```